# Adding volume slider and display time - React

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

Current instructions:

We've implemented the time control slider. Now implement the volume slider.

The time is currently displayed in seconds.

Add a method called formatTime to the Album component.

It should accept a time in seconds as a parameter and convert it into a string with the format of M:SS. Where ever the time is displayed, wrap it in this method.

(Bonus: If formatTime is passed an invalid/non-numeric value, it should return a fallback value of "-:--")

https://github.com/cjl85/bloc-jams-react/tree/master/src/components

Have four files Album, Landing (main page), Library, and PlayerBar.

When I render the page, everything runs except whenever I click the volume slider it gives me NaN.

Comment: If im not mistaken, the value for the volume slider is `value={(this.props.currentVolume / this.props.length) || 0}`? if thats the case, did you add to that render method a `console.log(`${this.props.currentVolume} || ${this.props.length}`)` to output the values? it could a divide-by-zero

Comment: Yeah I think you're right about the divide by zero but im not sure what you mean by adding the console.log in the render method. Right now, the volume slider doesn't slide and the moment I try to, it says NaN

Comment: Adding it here `class PlayerBar extends Component { render() { console.log(${this.props.currentVolume} || ${this.props.length}); return ( ... ); } }`

Comment: it's giving me a parsing error and it's pointing to the period in the console.log

Comment: You can do this instead, `console.log("current volume: ", this.props.currentVolume); console.log("length: ", this.props.length)`, just to get the values. if it outputs length: 0 or null or undefined then you found your problem

Comment: still giving that same error, but i see what you're saying